# SQL Server The initial backup restore works, the rest don't

Tags: sql, sql-server, backup

I'm trying to backup and restore a database in Sql Server 2014.
The initial backup restore works.
But when I make some changes to the database and repeat the backup/reload procedure
I get the data of the first backup losing the most recent changes.
Below is a script that illustrates the issue I'm facing

```
CREATE DATABASE sample;

CREATE TABLE list (
    id INT, 
    name VARCHAR(50)
);

--first record is inserted

BACKUP DATABASE sample to DISK='D:\Backup\sample.bak';

truncate table list;


GO
USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE sample
SET SINGLE_USER
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO
RESTORE DATABASE sample FROM DISK='D:\Backup\sample.bak' with REPLACE;
GO
ALTER DATABASE sample
SET MULTI_USER;
GO


--restored database contains one record
use sample;
select * from list;

--second record is inserted
insert into list values(2,'item_2');
select * from list;


BACKUP DATABASE sample to DISK='D:\Backup\sample.bak';

GO
USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE sample
SET SINGLE_USER
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO
RESTORE DATABASE sample FROM DISK='D:\Backup\sample.bak' with REPLACE;
GO
ALTER DATABASE sample
SET MULTI_USER;
GO

--restored database STILL contains one record
use sample;
select * from list;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your `backup database sample to disk='...'` statement by default APPENDS the new backup to the backup device (backup file). As the result, you then have multiple backups stored in the backup file.
When doing restore, you are restoring the first backup.

To solve the problem, you can specify to override the content of the backup file by using the "WITH INIT" parameter:

```sql
BACKUP DATABASE sample to DISK='D:\Backup\sample.bak' WITH INIT;
```

More docs can be found eg. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 2):

Use `WITH INIT` in your `BACKUP` statement to reinitialise the backup file.

On my Sandbox instance, the following:

```
CREATE DATABASE [sample];
GO

USE [sample];
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.list (i int,
                       s varchar(6));
GO

USE master;
GO

BACKUP DATABASE [sample]
    TO  DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SANDBOX\MSSQL\Backup\sample.bak'
    WITH INIT;
GO
USE [sample];
GO
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.list;

GO
USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE [sample] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO
RESTORE DATABASE [sample]
    FROM DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SANDBOX\MSSQL\Backup\sample.bak'
    WITH REPLACE;
GO
ALTER DATABASE [sample] SET MULTI_USER;
GO


--restored database contains no rows (none have been inserted yet
USE [sample];
GO
SELECT *
FROM dbo.list;

--first row is inserted
INSERT INTO dbo.list
VALUES (2, 'item_2');
SELECT *
FROM dbo.list;
GO
USE master;
GO
BACKUP DATABASE [sample]
    TO  DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SANDBOX\MSSQL\Backup\sample.bak'
    WITH INIT;

GO
ALTER DATABASE [sample] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO
RESTORE DATABASE [sample]
    FROM DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SANDBOX\MSSQL\Backup\sample.bak'
    WITH REPLACE;
GO
ALTER DATABASE [sample] SET MULTI_USER;
GO

--restored database STILL contains one record
USE [sample];
SELECT *
FROM dbo.list;
GO

USE master;
GO

DROP DATABASE [sample];
```

Create the datasets below:

[image]

As you can see, now the final `SELECT` retains the new row.

Otherwise, if you omit `INIT` in your `BACKUP` processes, you need to supply the position in the second `RESTORE`. In this case, it would be file 2:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [sample]
    FROM DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SANDBOX\MSSQL\Backup\sample.bak'
    WITH REPLACE, FILE = 2;
```

Animated GIF demonstrating (you'll likely want to open in a new window):

[image: Animated gif]

Answer (score 1):

When you use **the same file** to do `backup` in it without specifying `with init` in the backup command, the new backup is appended to the end of this file. This means after the second backup you'll have 2 backups in the same backup file.

When you `restore` from file that contains more than 1 `backup` you should specify `with file` and the name or the number of the backup in this file, otherwise the first `backup` will be used by deafult